# How to unhide extensions from status bar? vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidently clicked a option called `Hide 'Live Server'` from status bar in vs code and now I am not able to figure out how I can unhide that extension. Please help if you know how I can fix it.

That option looked like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the extension in the extension manager and click on the cog

[image]

Look for the setting `Show On Statusbar` and mark it as selected.

[image]